# Hover over text to fade menu in CSS

Tags: html, css

I am trying to fade in a menu(a div) when hovering over JUST the menu title.

Here is the HTML:

```
<p class="menu_Title"> //menu </p>
<div class = "menuitems">
     <a href="#">Profile</a><br>
     <a href="#">Experiences</a><br>
     <a href="#">Skills</a><br> 
     <a href="#">Contact</a><br>  
</div>
```

Here is the CSS:

```
.menuitems a {
    text-decoration: none;
}

.menuitems {
     opacity: 0;
     transition: opacity .25s ease-in; 
}

.menu_Title:hover .menuitems {
    transition-delay: 0.1s;
    opacity: 1;
}
```

I know that if I put the entire thing into a div and then hover the div it works (script is below) but there is a problem that occurs when doing this. I only want the menu to appear when hovering over the title and NOT the entire div. Does anyone have a solution to this?

'working' html:

```
<div class="h"> //ADDED THIS
    <p class="menu_Title"> //menu </p>
        <div class = "menuitems">
            <a href="#">Profile</a><br>
            <a href="#">Experiences</a><br>
            <a href="#">Skills</a><br> 
            <a href="#">Contact</a><br>  
        </div>
</div> //and this
```

'working' css:

```
.menu_Title:hover {
  letter-spacing: 3px; 
}

.menuitems a {
    text-decoration: none;
}

.menuitems{
     opacity: 0;
     transition: opacity .25s ease-in;       
}

.h:hover .menuitems{ //THIS IS THE ONLY LINE THAT CHANGES
    transition-delay: 0.1s;
    opacity: 1;    
}
```

Comment: As a tip, get rid of the `br` tags use `display:block;`  in your `.menuitems a` rule. https://jsfiddle.net/uze3yoyu/ . Your next problem will now be when you try to get to the child nav items.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

you have to use next sibling selector like this:

```
.menu_Title:hover + .menuitems{
  transition-delay: 0.1s;
  opacity: 1;
}
```

i have tested it and it works!

Comment: Thank you so much, this works!! I have a theory question if you do not mind. What is the difference between + and > ?

Comment: the `>` selector means parent-child relation i.e. when menuitems where inside the menu_Title element. but `+` means next sibling i.e. when menuitems are next to (not inside) the previous menu_Title item

Comment: Okay that makes sense. Thank you!

Answer (score 0):

try this....

```
.menu_Title:hover .menuitems > a {
   transition-delay: 0.1s;
   opacity: 1;
}
```

Comment: Thank you for your help. Instead of '>', I needed to use '+'.

Answer (score 0):

Try this.

```
.menu_Title:hover > .menuitems{
    transition-delay: 0.1s;
    opacity: 1;
}
```

this `>` will target to the next element (`.menuitems`).

Comment: Thank you for your help. Instead of '>', I needed to use '+'.

Comment: I just forgot it. sorry. :)

Comment: No problem! I did too haha

Answer (score 0):

just change your css to

```
.menu_Title:hover+.menuitems{
    transition-delay: 0.1s;
    opacity: 1;
}
```